# AWS Lambda: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named boto.ec2.autoscale

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-lambda

Following is the Lambda function, I wrote that gets the list of Autoscaling group and prints them.

```
import json
import boto3
import boto.ec2.autoscale

role = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/lambda-autoshutdown-role"
regions = ["eu-central-1"]
autoscaling = boto3.client('autoscaling')


class App(object):
  def __init__(self,RoleArn):
    self.RoleArn = RoleArn

    if self.RoleArn != "local":
      sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
      self.sts = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=self.RoleArn,
        RoleSessionName="lambda_poweroff")["Credentials"]

  def get_resource(self,region="eu-central-1"):
      if self.RoleArn == "local":
        return boto3.resource(region_name=region)
      else:
        return boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region(
          region_name=region,
          aws_access_key_id=self.sts['AccessKeyId'],
          aws_secret_access_key=self.sts['SecretAccessKey'],)



def lambda_handler(event, context):

  a = App(role)

  for region in regions:
    asgs = a.get_resource(region)
    # locate all running instances
    #autoscaling_groups_to_suspend = []
    #for i in asgs:
     #   print asgs[i]
    print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, asgs))
```

This function uses: `boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region` to connect and returns the object.

But when I try to deploy it on AWS, I get the following error:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named boto.ec2.autoscale
```

It seems like the class boto.ec2.autoscale is not being loaded by AWS.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone looking for an answer, the following piece of Lambda code gets the lists of all ASG's and then suspends them (except the ones that match the regrex)

```
import json
import boto3


regions = ["eu-central-1"]
autoscaling = boto3.client('autoscaling')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  response = autoscaling.describe_auto_scaling_groups(MaxRecords=100)
  #print response
  #print(response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['AutoScalingGroupName'])
  autoscaling_group_to_suspend = []
  for doc in response['AutoScalingGroups']:
    response_parsed = doc['AutoScalingGroupName']
    autoscaling_group_to_suspend.append(response_parsed)

  #print autoscaling_group_to_suspend
  import re
  regex = re.compile(r'es-data-asg|consul|influxdb|vault|es-master')
  filtered = filter(lambda i: not regex.search(i), autoscaling_group_to_suspend)
  filtered = [i for i in autoscaling_group_to_suspend if not regex.search(i)]
  print filtered

  if len(filtered) > 0:
    for x in filtered:
        autoscaling.suspend_processes(AutoScalingGroupName=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing with s3. I need boto.s3.connect_to_region() but I get the same error. Probably importing the boto module in the lambda dependency might solve the issue. Else, we might have to use boto3.client and parse the json response to get the appropriate values.